# custom JAVA home for Logstash

Tags: java, logstash

I have an centOS server with JAVA 10 Installed. While I am trying to install  logstash on this server,It seems Logstash is not supported JAVA 10. But I need JAVA 10 on this server for wildfly.
What is the recommendations to install logstash with lower version of JAVA in this server? 
I am ready to install both JAVA in this server and use the lower version for logstash. IN what configuration I may need to update on logstash to use it JAVA 8?

Answer (score 0):

If you start Logastash as a service then you should modify `/etc/init.d/logstash`, there is a variable called `JAVA`. Assign to `JAVA` variable path to Java 8. `checkJava()` method inside of the file looks for correct Java and replaces `JAVA_HOME` with `LS_USER` so you could also try to export this variable before starting Logstash.